# Connecting an Arduino Nano ESP32 board to Arduino Data Logging Shield

Tags: python-3.x, camera, arduino-esp32, datalog, arduino-nano

I have an Arduino Data Logging Shield hooked up to an Arduino Mega. Now I need to hook it up to a camera module to take photos and analyze them using a Python script. To be more specific, the Python script will analyze the photos to determine the presence of fires in the photos. Since Arduino Mega doesn't support Python, I intend to get an Arduino Nano ESP32 board and program it with micropython to do the job for me but then how do I connect the ESP32 board to the Data Logging shield to save the JPG files after the photos have been taken?

I initially thought the Chip select pin (*pin 10*) would be the ideal pin on the logging shield to connect to but I am not really sure how that will work. Before making the purchase, I want to be sure the connection will work since it's not that cheap.